# Determine rotation of an object with two orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I have two orthogonal projections (i.e. radon transform to X and Y axis) of an 2D object in XY plane.

The object is rotated $\alpha$ degree respect to coordinate system.

Now I have new orthogonal projections, again in X and Y axis.

The question is that having orthogonal projections of an object before and after rotation, can I calculate rotation angle $\alpha$? If yes, how?

Thanks.

---

### Edit:

1- The object is black and white (0 and 1)

2- Regarding projection to an axis I mean (here projection to $x$): $p(x) = \int_{a}^{b}p(x,y)dy$

Like this image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1R9F.jpg)

3- The object is not symmetric in the range of rotation (neither centrally nor axially symmetric)

Comment: Could you precise, because saying "Radon transform" may hide a lot of things: 1) What is the nature of the object traversed : black/white or levels of gray ? 2) What is the nature of what you call "projections" ; is it attenuation curves ? Is attenuation at a point linearly proportional to the length of intersection of the ray with the object or is it an integral if the framework is levels of gray ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I added more description, hope the problem be more clear now.

Comment: Your object could be rotationally symmetric, in which case the projection after a rotation will equal the projection before rotation. Thus, you cannot in general obtain $\alpha$. It may be possible to find $\alpha$ if your object is "sufficiently assymetric".

Comment: @Wouter  The object is not symmetric in the range of rotation

Comment: Do you mean neither centrally nor axially symmetric ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  Yes, neither centrally nor axially symmetric